# ExecutionResult result.hasNext() taking very long time to return

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am fairly new to Neo4j. I am running into a peculiar error when trying to iterate over a ExecutionResult result set. In the following code snippet, the last res.hasNext() takes close to 50 seconds to return on the last iteration.

The cypher query I am using is

```
start p=node(*) where (p.`process-workflowID`? = '" + Id + "') and (p.type? = 'process') return ID(p);
```

I am using neo4j-community-1.8.1 and java 1.6.0_41, testing against a DB with 226710 nodes.

Does anyone have any clue as to why this is happening?  I assume the query is done when engine.execute(query) returns, but if this isn't the case, would appreciate someone shedding some light on when the query actually gets completed. Thank you in advance.

```
ExecutionResult result = engine.execute(query);
Iterator<Map<String, Object>> res =  result.iterator();
while(res.hasNext()) {
   Map<String, Object> row = res.next();
   for(Entry<String, Object> column : row.entrySet()){
                ...
   }
   long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
   res.hasNext(); // <--------------------------- statement in question
   long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
   System.out.println(t2-t1);
}
```

Comment: Please post the cypher query you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Queries are performed while iterating over the result set. So each call to hasNext/next involves some operation on the graph. Nevertheless a pause of 50 secs with a graph off ~250k nodes indicates that you are doing something basically wrong.

You might look into:

1. Your query is very inefficient, you should make use of indexes. The most easy way is to setup autoindexing for the properties you're searching for, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/auto-indexing.html. Please note that pre-existing data does not get reindexed!

   After rebuilding the database use the following cypher statement instead:

   ```
   Map<String,Object> = Collections.singletonMap("id", Id);
   executionEngine.execute("start p=node:node_auto_index('process-workflowID:{id} type:process') return ID(p)", params)
   ```

   I'm not sure if "process-workflowID" needs additional quoting in lucene syntax.
2. make sure that you're not suffering from gc/memory issues using e.g. jvisualvm
3. Setup mapped memory according to http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/configuration-caches.html and run your query more than once to benefit from warmed up caches.

Comment: Very helpful explanation! Could you bother to explain more about what you mean by 'pre-existing data does not get reindexed'? Does it mean that I have to setup indexes first, and reingest my data? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: exactly. Changes to autonindexing setup will not change current index contents, they are just updating the indexes upon each data change from the timepoint of config change on.